# Liberty for Java App Starter Code Issue on Eclipse

Tags: ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

I hope that you can help me on this one.

I created a Liberty for Java App on Bluemix, downloaded the starter code, and imported it to my Java EE IDE(Eclipse Neon). Unfortunately I am getting this type of error:

> Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for
>   net.wasdev.wlp.sample:JavaHelloWorldApp:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to
>   transfer net.wasdev.maven.parent:java7-parent:pom:1.4 from
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error:
>   Could not transfer artifact
>   net.wasdev.maven.parent:java7-parent:pom:1.4 from/to central
>   (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection refused: connect
>   and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM

Comment: are you connecting from behind the proxy?

Comment: are you able to ping the maven URL indicated in the exception message?